# Trying to understand the difference between various batteries for Lenovo Thinkpad T520

Tags: battery, thinkpad

There are various types of batteries for the laptop and I'm not sure which one is best. The one I have right now (which came with it), is not enough to last me through my back-to-back classes, so I am looking to replace it, hopefully with one with a better ability to hold a charge. I don't know much about the hardware side of computers, which is why I am hoping that someone can let me know what difference there is between them.

For clarification, I looked at [this site](http://www.battdepot.com/ca/model/lenovo/ThinkPad+T520.aspx?gclid=CN3K3LLBqscCFZRffgod7PQH8A), which doesn't tell me if it is 4, 6 or 9 cell.

Answer (score 0):

This information comes from the [specs](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd015761#pow):

- A 6- or 9-cell Li-Ion battery pack is shipped with the system.
- Supports optional Slice battery as second battery at bottom.
- Battery life:

  - 4-cell: up to 2 hours
  - 6-cell: up to 2.5 hours
  - 9-cell: 3.75 hours
  - 9-cell plus Slice battery: up to 3.75 hours

Notes:

- Battery life (and recharge times) will vary based on many factors including screen brightness, applications, features, power management, battery conditioning and other customer preferences.

It appears that the OEM batteries have the following capacities:

- 6-cell: 5200 mAh, 57Wh
- 9-cell: 8700 mAh, 94 Wh

The site you linked to sells third party batteries that are not an exact match to the OEM batteries.  One is 4400 mAh and one is 6600 mAh.  If they actually work and are comparable in other respects, the 4400 would have a run time of a little over 2 hours and the 6600 would have a run time of a little over 3 hours.

My own experience with off-brand replacement batteries has been pretty bad (very short life, some DOA).  I pay more to get the OEM batteries, which typically use higher quality cells.  The prices at the site you linked to are substantially higher than what I spotted OEM batteries selling for, so I wouldn't see any reason to risk them.